# Ns3 LTE simulation: UDP-server-client setup, issues with sending and receiving

Tags: c++, sockets, ns-3

"I have the following code. I want to send packets from one UDP client socket belonging to Node 1 to three other server sockets belonging to Node 1, 2, and 3 (one of the server sockets belongs to the same node as the sending socket). I have a callback function that should execute on receive. The issue I'm facing is that the callback function is only called on receive for the socket that is on the same IP as the sending socket. When sending, it looks like the packet is sent but it is not received. Why isn't the callback function called for the other sockets? All advice is appreciated. The code is as follows, and prints are provided. Thank you in advance."

```
NodeContainer ueNodes;
ueNodes.Create(3);

NodeContainer enbNodes;
enbNodes.Create(1);



MobilityHelper mobility;
mobility.SetMobilityModel("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
// Set positions for the nodes to achieve a fixed distance
Ptr<ListPositionAllocator> positionAlloc = CreateObject<ListPositionAllocator>();
positionAlloc->Add(Vector(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)); // Position for the first node (0,0,0)
positionAlloc->Add(Vector(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)); // Position for the second node (1,0,0)
positionAlloc->Add(Vector(2.0, 0.0, 0.0)); // Position for the second node (2,0,0)
mobility.SetPositionAllocator(positionAlloc);
mobility.Install(ueNodes);
mobility.Install(enbNodes);



// Create the LTE channel
Ptr<LteHelper> lteHelper = CreateObject<LteHelper>();

// Install LTE devices
NetDeviceContainer enbDevs;
NetDeviceContainer ueDevs;
enbDevs = lteHelper->InstallEnbDevice(enbNodes);
ueDevs = lteHelper->InstallUeDevice(ueNodes);
lteHelper->SetEnbDeviceAttribute("DlBandwidth", UintegerValue(25));
lteHelper->SetEnbDeviceAttribute("UlBandwidth", UintegerValue(25));

// attach must attach for some reason.
lteHelper->Attach(ueDevs, enbDevs.Get(0));
// Activate a data radio bearer
EpsBearer::Qci q = EpsBearer::GBR_CONV_VOICE;
EpsBearer bearer(q);
lteHelper->ActivateDataRadioBearer(ueDevs, bearer);
// lteHelper->EnableTraces();

// Install internet stack on nodes
InternetStackHelper internet;
internet.Install(ueNodes);
internet.Install(enbNodes);

// Assign IP addresses to devices
Ipv4AddressHelper ipv4;
ipv4.SetBase("192.168.1.0", "255.255.255.0");
Ipv4InterfaceContainer ueIpIfaces;
Ipv4InterfaceContainer enbIpIfaces;
ueIpIfaces = ipv4.Assign(ueDevs);
enbIpIfaces = ipv4.Assign(enbDevs);

// Create application container for client and server app
ApplicationContainer clientApps, serverApps;
std::vector<InetSocketAddress> bindAdresses;
std::vector<Address> remoteAdresses;
uint16_t udpServerPort = 9;



//ip address for node 1
Ptr<Ipv4> ip1 = ueNodes.Get(0)->GetObject<Ipv4>();
Ipv4Address IpAddress1 = ip1->GetAddress(1, 0).GetLocal();
std::cout << "Address1 " << IpAddress1 << std::endl;

//ip address for node 2
Ptr<Ipv4> ip2 = ueNodes.Get(1)->GetObject<Ipv4>();
Ipv4Address IpAddress2 = ip2->GetAddress(1, 0).GetLocal();
std::cout << "Address2 " << IpAddress2 << std::endl;

//ip address for node 3
Ptr<Ipv4> ip3 = ueNodes.Get(2)->GetObject<Ipv4>();
Ipv4Address IpAddress3 = ip3->GetAddress(1, 0).GetLocal();
std::cout << "Address3 " << IpAddress3 << std::endl;
IpAddress3 = ip3->GetAddress(0, 0).GetLocal();


//create socket for node 1,2,3
Ptr<Socket> serverSocket1 = Socket::CreateSocket(ueNodes.Get(0), UdpSocketFactory::GetTypeId());
std::cout << "p1" << std::endl;
Ptr<Socket> serverSocket2 = Socket::CreateSocket(ueNodes.Get(1), UdpSocketFactory::GetTypeId());
std::cout << "p2" << std::endl;
Ptr<Socket> serverSocket3 = Socket::CreateSocket(ueNodes.Get(2), UdpSocketFactory::GetTypeId());
std::cout << "p3" << std::endl;
InetSocketAddress bindAdress1 = InetSocketAddress(Ipv4Address("192.168.1.1"), udpServerPort); //address for server socket to bind to
std::cout << "p4" << std::endl;
InetSocketAddress bindAdress2 = InetSocketAddress(Ipv4Address("192.168.1.2"), udpServerPort); //address for server socket to bind to
std::cout << "p5" << std::endl;
InetSocketAddress bindAdress3 = InetSocketAddress(Ipv4Address("192.168.1.3"), udpServerPort); //address for server socket to bind to
std::cout << "p6" << std::endl;

//Callback function to be called when packet is received
serverSocket1 -> SetRecvCallback(MakeCallback(ReceiveCallback));
std::cout << "p7" << std::endl;
serverSocket2->SetRecvCallback(MakeCallback(ReceiveCallback));
std::cout << "p8" << std::endl;
serverSocket3->SetRecvCallback(MakeCallback(ReceiveCallback));
std::cout << "p9" << std::endl;

//Bind the server sockets to each address
//if bounded returns 0
int bounded;
bounded = serverSocket1->Bind(bindAdress1);
std::cout << "bound to: " << InetSocketAddress::ConvertFrom(bindAdress1).GetIpv4()
          << "with status: " << bounded << std::endl;
bounded = serverSocket2->Bind(bindAdress2);
std::cout << "bound to: " << InetSocketAddress::ConvertFrom(bindAdress2).GetIpv4()
          << "with status: " << bounded << std::endl;
bounded = serverSocket3->Bind(bindAdress3);
std::cout << "bound to: " << InetSocketAddress::ConvertFrom(bindAdress3).GetIpv4()
          << "with status: " << bounded << std::endl;

//create client sockets only want client sockets for node 1
Ptr<Socket> clientSocket1 = Socket::CreateSocket(ueNodes.Get(0), UdpSocketFactory::GetTypeId());



//sends data from each client socket on node 1 to each serverver socket on node 1,2,3 (one server socket per node)
//if packet is sent returns the size of the packet size of str "Hello, NS-3!"
int sent;
std::string data = "Hello, NS-3!";
Ptr<Packet> packet = Create<Packet>((uint8_t*)data.c_str(), data.size());
sent = clientSocket1->SendTo(packet,0,bindAdress1);                                                       //send to server socket on node 1 ip
std::cout << "sent data: " << data << "with status: " << sent
          << "to: " << InetSocketAddress::ConvertFrom(bindAdress1).GetIpv4() << std::endl;
sent = clientSocket1->SendTo(packet,0,bindAdress2);                                                        //send to server socket on node 2 ip
std::cout << "sent data: " << data << "with status: " << sent
          << "to: " << InetSocketAddress::ConvertFrom(bindAdress2).GetIpv4() << std::endl;
sent = clientSocket1->SendTo(packet,0,bindAdress3);                                                       //send to server socket on node 3 ip
std::cout << "sent data: " << data << "with status: " << sent
          << "to: " << InetSocketAddress::ConvertFrom(bindAdress3).GetIpv4() << std::endl;
// Start and run the simulation
Simulator::Stop(Seconds(20.0));
Simulator::Run();
Simulator::Destroy();




return 0;
```

### Prints:

- Address1 192.168.1.1
- Address2 192.168.1.2
- Address3 192.168.1.3
- p1
- p2
- p3
- p4
- p5
- p6
- p7
- p8
- p9
- bound to: 192.168.1.1with status: 0
- bound to: 192.168.1.2with status: 0
- bound to: 192.168.1.3with status: 0
- received packet: 0x56518415e1d0from ip: 192.168.1.1
- sent data: Hello, NS-3!with status: 12to: 192.168.1.1
- sent data: Hello, NS-3!with status: 12to: 192.168.1.2
- sent data: Hello, NS-3!with status: 12to: 192.168.1.3

Comment: "it looks like the packet is sent but it is not received" - The UDP protocol does not guarantee delivery - you have to be prepared to deal with lost packets (as well as packets arriving out-of-order). If you want guaranteed and in-order delivery; use TCP instead of UDP or be prepared to handle all the packet reordering and retransmission yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I now sent 100 packets to each of the sockets, every one gets through to the socket on the same IP as the sending socket but no other got through. I belive I can therefore safley say there is some missconfiguration, but I dont se where. Creating another client socket on node 2 and sending it to the server socket on its address works just fine. I can only send packets from a client to a server if the client has the same ip as the server. Any thoughts ?

Comment: " I now sent 100 packets to each of the sockets, every one gets through to the socket on the same IP as the sending socket" - doesn't prove anything. But, in any case; maybe you have some firewall rules in place that block some packets? Maybe, for the sake of experiment, try disabling your local firewall.

Comment: It is a simulation software, it should not have an effect if I disable the firewall. But I tried it, no effect on the simulation.